# Unlink state form store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I've had a problem

```
  data() {
    return {
      list: [],
      initState: { id: null, data: null }
    }
  },
  computed: {    
     ...mapState({
        contacts: (state) => state.ContactBook.Contacts
      })
     },},
      methods: {
        setinitState(payload) {
          this.initState.data = contacts[this.contactID]
        },
```

How Can I make **this.initState** static? I need **this.initState** didnt changes when **contacts[this.contactID]** changes...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

state.snapshot = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.Contacts[payload]))

Answer (score 1):

You may use the spread operator like this,

```js
this.initState.data = {...contacts[this.contanctID]}
```

[Spread Operator MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: No it doesnt work(, but method JSON stringlify -> JsonParse worked well